# MongoDB insert operation using Groovy script for Jmeter

Tags: mongodb, groovy, jmeter

i am trying to load test MongoDB using Jmeter, i am using JSR223Sampler using Groovy, i am able to connect but for some reason insert part is not working
 i need to insert below :
"cart" : {
        "schema" : "http://dell.com/dcp/schemas/cart/3.0.0#",
        "_id" : "s5ChQonvAUGKM6s2Yq8Z31",
        "createdOn" : {
            "DateTime" : ISODate("2018-03-07T06:54:01.242Z"),
            "Ticks" : NumberLong(636560222412422269),
            "Offset" : 330
        },
        "lastModifiedOn" : {
            "DateTime" : ISODate("2018-03-07T06:54:01.245Z"),
            "Ticks" : NumberLong(636560222412452266),
            "Offset" : 330
        },
        "expiresOn" : {
            "DateTime" : ISODate("2019-04-10T08:21:43.984Z"),
            "Ticks" : NumberLong(636904813039840000),
            "Offset" : 0
        },
        "commerceContext" : {
            "region" : "us",
            "country" : "US",
            "language" : "en",
            "currency" : "USD",
            "segment" : "bsd",
            "customerSet" : "rc1005388",
            "accessGroup" : "DSA",
            "companyNumber" : "08",
            "businessUnitId" : "11",
            "classCode" : "string",
            "sourceApplicationName" : "OLRGCOMM"
        },
        "items" : [],
        "shipments" : [],
        "price" : {
         "couponCodes" : []
        },
        "references" : [ 
            {
                "referenceId" : "8TOOOrdEJUeiGPTqWA226Q",
                "referenceType" : "New Cart",
                "referencedOn" : {
                    "DateTime" : ISODate("2018-03-07T06:54:01.239Z"),
                    "Ticks" : NumberLong(636560222412392112),
                    "Offset" : 330
                },
                "referenceCreatedBy" : "DCQO",
                "targetSystem" : "DSP",
                "target" : "string"
            }
        ],
        "validation" : {},
        "properties" : {}
    }
})

Comment: i got it working

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all you need to get MongoDB connection from the [MongoDB Source Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#MongoDB_Source_Config_(DEPRECATED)), it can be done as follows:

   ```
   import com.mongodb.DB;
   import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.mongodb.config.MongoDBHolder;

   DB db = MongoDBHolder.getDBFromSource("mongodb source name", "database name");
   ```
2. Next you just need to call [DBCollection.insert()](https://api.mongodb.com/java/2.1/com/mongodb/DBCollection.html#insert(com.mongodb.DBObject...)) function like:

   ```
   db.getCollection('your collection name').insert(your DBObject payload here)
   ```

More information: [How to Load Test MongoDB with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-mongodb-jmeter)

Comment: thank you Dmitri, now i am stuck with the nested array  part , how to add nested array to a document , please find below sample                                    
 "items": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      
      },
      {
      "id": "1",
      
      },
   ]